# Problems with base64 and socket in Python

Tags: python, base64

I am programming a remote `cmd` with extra commands. I want to use Base64 encoding, to make the traffic just a bit more secure. When I run the script and type a command, the server prints the below message:

`Disconnected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55206)`

But the client still thinks it's connected.
I tried it without Base64 encoding and it worked!

Here is the code:

**server:**

```
#admin server
import socket
import base64

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

local_pc = '127.0.0.1'
port = 12345
s.bind((local_pc, port))
s.listen()

while True:
    print("Server listening")
    conn, addr = s.accept ()
    print("Connection to: ", addr)

    try:
        while True:
            command = input("Command: ")

            command_bytes = command.encode("ascii")
            command_b64_bytes = base64.b64decode(command_bytes)
            command_b64_string = command_b64_bytes.decode("ascii")

            conn.sendall(command_b64_string.encode())

            data_b64_string = conn.recv(5000)
            data_b64_bytes = data_b64_string  # .encode("ascii")
            data_string_bytes = base64.b64decode(data_b64_bytes)
            data = data_string_bytes.decode("ascii")
            # decoded = data.decode(encoding = 'UTF-8',errors = 'ignore')
            # print(decoded)
            print(data)

    except:
        print("Disconnected from: ", addr)
```

**client:**

```
#client
import socket
import subprocess
import os
import base64

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 12345
message = "Messagebox executed"
msg_title = ''
msg_part = "WScript.Shell"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print("Established connection to: ", host, ":", port)
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    data_b64 = s.recv(5000)
    data_b64_bytes = data_b64#.encode("ascii")
    data_bytes = base64.b64decode(data_b64_bytes)
    data = data_bytes.decode("ascii")

    print("Executed: ", data)

    if data.find("message") >= 0:
        message_cmd = "mshta \"javascript:var sh=new ActiveXObject( 'WScript.Shell' ); sh.Popup( '" + (data.partition(' ')[2]) + "', 10, '', 64 );close()\""   #mshta "javascript:var sh=new ActiveXObject( 'WScript.Shell' ); sh.Popup( 'Message!', 10, 'Title!', 64 );close()"
        os.system('cmd /c' + message_cmd)
        s.sendall(message.encode())
    else:

        op = subprocess.Popen(data, shell = True,
                          stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdin = subprocess.PIPE)

        report = op.stdout.read().decode(encoding = 'UTF-8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
        report_error = op.stderr.read().decode(encoding = 'UTF-8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
        print(report)
        print(report_error)

        report_bytes = report.encode("ascii")
        report_error_bytes = report.encode("ascii")

        report_b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(report_bytes)
        report_error_b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(report_bytes)

        report_b64_string = report_b64_bytes.decode("ascii")
        report_error_b64_string = report_b64_bytes.decode("ascii")

        s.sendall(report_b64_string.encode())
        s.sendall(report_error_b64_string.encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the conversion in the server code. You try to decode your `ASCII` string to `base64`. However, you have to encode the `ASCII` string into `base64`.

To solve the problem simply replace this line:

```
command_b64_bytes = base64.b64decode(command_bytes)
```

by this one:

```
command_b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(command_bytes)
```

P.S.: I don't think that `base64` adds any security as anyone can decode it.